# How to record sound from a microphone in VB6?

Tags: vb6, audio, microphone, recording

We've been recording sound for over a decade using what seems like a very clunky method using the Winmm.dll and the MCIsendString.

I've [read](http://www.rediware.com/programming/vb/vbrecwav/vbrecordwav.htm) that this doesn't set the recording quality value correctly (not sure if that article was ever true or is still true).

I was wondering if there is any better way to record sound, such as using the MCI control, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one alternative way:

[**This alternative to MCISend**](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=65662&lngWId=1) is really complicated but does some neat stuff like:
 * Setting volume
 * Displaying sound meter in real time.
 * Displaying waveform in real time.

And I found some tips that may make the MCISendString work a bit better:

1. [This fellow](http://www.rediware.com/programming/vb/vbrecwav/vbrecordwav.htm) claims that the MCISendString has a flaw (transposes some digits in some of the settings) which can cause the audio to not be playable in Windows Media Player.
2. [Someone reported needing to set the MCISendString parameters very carefully](http://www.codenewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/topic11285.aspx) in a way not fully documented. This was in response to a report of poor recording quality.

Comment: The link to planet-source-code is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

"Clunky" is right.  I've also been using the MciSendString method.  If you are willing to move off VB6, you could use the [Microphone support in Silverlight 4](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-camera-and-microphone-support.aspx).  Combined with the out of browser support, it could conceivably replace you VB6 app. (sorry, long shot).